# How to make draggable revert if dropped in the wrong place

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

The draggables in my drag and drop game should only be able to be dropped in the designated area highlighted by the css.

```
$('.drag').draggable({

helper: 'clone',
snap: '.drop',
grid: [60, 60],
revert: 'invalid'
});


$('.drop').droppable ({
drop: function(event, ui) {
    word = $(this).data('word');

   }
});
```

The CSS style is called .showword, and the click event that triggers it is called "#picknext".

**Any ideas how I would get the draggable to revert if it wasn't dropped in the styled area?**

Something like this...

```
$('#picknext').click({
drop: function(event, ui) {
    word = $(this).data('word');
}       

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is something that should get you started.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#revert

Comment: I have. That is where I learnt how to do what I have so far, but I cannot figure out how to make the draggable revert if they are dropped outside of the styled area @Shouvik

Answer (score 0):

Rather than having a function for your `revert` property you want to set it to invalid as discussed in that options help: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Draggable#option-revert

Comment: What would I then put in drop for it to only accept if its in the ".showword" style? @Chris

Comment: You'll want to look at the `droppable` functionality. Sorry, I had assumed that you had already got the droppable bit sorted. :) If you have any troubles with it though best to start a new question and keep this one just about the revert.